# Build an Lambda expression from an propertypath

Tags: linq, lambda

Hi lets say I have an property path looking like this

We can say that I have an article that has an Vat and Vat has an Value.
Now I want to use Linq to sort a list using that property path
How can I build that lambda expression when I have "Vat.Value" in a string and I want the following result

```
list.Order(x => x.Vat.Value)
```

I will not always know the types of Vat and Value, sometimes its only x.Name I'm out for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you cannot use the existing LINQ Dynamic Query library, which has overloads which take strings?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

It might be doing the same thing you just wrote, but its code that you don't have to maintain and may have some optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it with an extension method. The approach to use an propertypath now is for example

```
var orderedArticles = articles.OrderBy("Vat.Value");
```

instead of

```
var orderedArticles = articles.OrderBy(x => x.Vat.Value)
```

Extension methods:

```
private static Func<T, TReturnType> GetLambda<T, TReturnType>(IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
{
    var rootParameterExression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    Expression expression = rootParameterExression;
    foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
    {
        expression = Expression.Property(expression, propertyName);
    }
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TReturnType>>(expression, rootParameterExression).Compile();
}

public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> queryable, string propertyPath)
{
    var propertyPathList = propertyPath.Split(Convert.ToChar("."));
    Type propertyType = typeof(T);
    foreach (var propertyName in propertyPathList)
    {
        propertyType = propertyType.GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType;
    }

    if(propertyType == typeof(decimal))
    {
        var lambda = GetLambda<T, Decimal>(propertyPathList);
        return queryable.OrderBy(lambda);
    }
    var lamda = GetLambda<T, object>(propertyPathList);
    return queryable.OrderBy(lamda);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but something like this looks like what you want. Note that I'd probably refactor the lambda into a helper method in production for clarity. Also note that using reflection like this may be a significant performance hit depending on how large your collection is.

```
[Test]
public void OrderByUsingReflection()
{
    var values = new[] 
    {
        new { Vat = new { Value = "two"}},
        new { Vat = new {Value = "one"}},
    };

    var result = values.OrderBy(x =>
    {
        var vat = x.GetType().GetProperty("Vat").GetValue(x, null);
        return vat.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(vat, null);
    });

    Assert.AreEqual(result.ToList()[0], values[1]);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.ToList()[1], values[0]);
}
```

Comment: I think the one I posted now is more performance efficient and easier to use.